# Does there exist a topology for a set X  which is compact and Hausdorff?

Tags: gn.general-topology

For every set $X$ and every topology $\tau$ over $X$ we have that $\tau$ contains the trivial topology $\{ X, \emptyset\}$, which is compact, and is contained in the discrete topology $\{ S: S \subseteq X\}$, which is Hausdorff. I was wondering if there is any topology on X "between" the trivial and the discrete such that it has both properties.

It seems that there is such a topology for specific sets, such as the natural numbers, but I haven't found any result for arbitrary $X$. I don't know if any additional condition must be established on $X$ for the result to hold, or if it isn't possible in general.

Comment: Successor ordinals.


Comment: Or one point compactifications of discrete spaces, in case you want to avoid the axiom of choice.

Comment: Crossposted at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358583/does-there-exist-a-topology-for-a-set-x-which-is-compact-and-hausdorff

Comment: A silly solution: Pick one element x.  Declare every finite set NOT containing x to be open.  Declare the COMPLEMENT of every finite set NOT containing x to be open.  This is a compact Hausdorff topology.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Not silly at all, although I think it's the same as the one-point compactification mentioned by Ramiro. Same applies to Peter's answer of course.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $x_0\in X$ and declare as open neighborhoods of $x_0$ the subsets which contain $x_0$ and all but finitely many of the points of $X$. Declare all other points of $X$ as open. This is Hausdorff and compact.

Comment: And the empty set is trivially ok. ;)